# Core 6.0 Web API Localization IStringLocalizer selecting incorrect culture

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm developing a Web API project using Core 6.0 with localization.

I used a few online guides, primarily [this one](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/how-to-use-localization-in-an-asp-net-core-web-api.aspx)

I am using an external library for the resources.

`Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization();

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US");
    options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("he-IL"),
        new CultureInfo("ru-RU")
    };
    options.RequestCultureProviders = new[] { new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider { IndexOfCulture = 3 } };
});

builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => 
{
    options.ConstraintMap.Add("lang", typeof(LanguageRouteConstraint));
});

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>? localizationOptions = app.Services.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();

if (localizationOptions != null)
    app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions.Value);

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Extension methods:

```
public class LanguageRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContext? httpContext, IRouter? route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (!values.ContainsKey("lang"))
            return false;

        string? culture = values["lang"]?.ToString();
        return culture == "en-US" || culture == "he-IL" || culture == "ru-RU";
    }
}


public class RouteDataRequestCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
{
    public int IndexOfCulture;

    public override Task<ProviderCultureResult?> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));

        string? culture = httpContext.Request.Path.Value is not null && httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/').Length > IndexOfCulture ? httpContext.Request.Path.Value?.Split('/')[IndexOfCulture]?.ToString() : null;

        ProviderCultureResult? providerResultCulture = culture is null ? null : new(culture);

        return Task.FromResult(providerResultCulture);
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]/{lang:lang?}")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    public AccountController(IStringLocalizer<LangRes.App> localizer) : base(localizer)
    {
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {
        return Ok(GetErrorMessage("TEST"));
    }
}
```

And BaseController:

```
[Route("")]
[ApiController]
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<LangRes.App> localizer;

    public BaseController(IStringLocalizer<LangRes.App> localizer)
    {
        this.localizer = localizer;
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage(string result)
    {
        return localizer.GetString(result);
    }
}
```

The external library `LangRes` has an empty `App` class and

`App.en-US.resx` with `TEST` key as `This is english` as value

`App.he-IL.resx` with `TEST` key as `This is hebrew` as value

`App.ru-RU.resx` with `TEST` key as `This is russian` as value

when `options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US")` is used, both `account/Test/he-IL` and `account/Test/ru-RU` are not matched and the localizer uses the fallback `en-US`, so the response is `This is english`.

when `options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "he-IL")` is used:

`account/Test/ru-RU` is not matched and the localizer uses the fallback `he-IL`

However `account/Test/en-US` does match correctly and the result is `This is english`!

when `options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "ru-RU")` is used:

`account/Test/he-IL` is not matched and the localizer uses the fallback `ru-RU`

However `account/Test/en-US` does match correctly and the result is `This is english`!

Debugging shows that `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` is returning the correct `ProviderCultureResult` culture for each request.

What am I missing here? It doesn't seem to be expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web API controllers dependency injection of `IStringLocalizer` depends on `UiCulture`, not `Culture`.

So this erratic behavior was caused since I did not define `SupportedUICultures` in the options of `RequestLocalizationOptions`.

Complete change in `Program.cs`:

```
List<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new()
{
    new CultureInfo("en-us"),
    new CultureInfo("he-il"),
    new CultureInfo("ru")
};

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "ru");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures; // important bit
    options.RequestCultureProviders = new[] { new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider { IndexOfCulture = 3 } };
});
```